# Box API and OAuth

Tags: api, oauth, box-api

My problem is we have a desktop app (i.e. not web based) which needs to communicate with the box API, from what I can tell OAuth which box uses for authorization, thats difficult to get that situation to work.

Does anyone have some sample C# code to show how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i accomplished this

1. Created a form using the WebBrowser control
2. Using that form, navigated to the URL provided by the "GetAuthorizationUrl" method on the TokenProvider.  Since I needed to provide a redirect URL I used a website associated with our company.  The website would not actually "handle" this redirect request, but that was ok.
3. After entering  my box user id/password and allowing access, the browser control is redirected to the URL specified.  Embedded in that URL is the the temporary access token.   I had a "Document Completed" event on the WebBrowser so I looked to see if the URL contained the string "code=".
4. Parsing the URL to get the temporary code I then used the TokenProvider to return the OAuthToken.
5. From the OAuthToken I could use the [box-csharp-sdk-v2] to create a BoxManager object that handled all the Box API calls.

To be honest its a little kludgy, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

to use Box API For Windows U Can use JWT Authentication which generate a token based on ClientId, Client Secret,Private key ,Public Key And Enterprise key .

this token Will Provided On user basic 
there Are Two types of user 
1.Admin
2.App user

so there is no need to Login
reference Doc: 
https://box-content.readme.io/docs/app-auth

Box Windows SDK
https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2